# Xamarin HTTPClient suddenly not GET/POSTing

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

Long time lurker, first time asker

So I've got some code which has been working fine for a long, long time (it's core functionality, so I know it's been fine). I've recently formatted my PC, which has understandably reset all my custom configs over time. Now suddenly, my HTTPClient code doesn't GET or POST at all, unless I break the Async functionality - and even that breaks other things. I've let it run, and the client ends up timing out.

The code is dying at the `hClient.GetStringAsync()` and `hClient.PostAsync()` lines below - as I mentioned, it's been fine for almost 2 years, just suddenly decided to die following the format. All help appreciated!

Background: This is a Xamarin PCL project, targetting all platforms - currently testing against UWP. Have had the same issue on both VS2015 and VS2017. Was previously using VS2015.

The code in question:

```
public async Task<string> Getter(string uriToPass, string propertyToParse = "", string parent = "", int index = 0)
{
    var uri = new Uri(uriToPass);
    var response = await hClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    string valToReturn = propertyToParse == "" ? response : JsonVal(response, propertyToParse, parent);
    dbg(propertyToParse + ": " + valToReturn);
    return valToReturn;
}

public async Task<string> Poster(string uriToPass, Dictionary<string, string> valsToPass, string propertyToParse = "", string parent = "", int index = 0)
{
    var response = await hClient.PostAsync(uriToPass, new FormUrlEncodedContent(valsToPass)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    string valToReturn;
    if (propertyToParse == "")
    {
        valToReturn = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        valToReturn = JsonVal(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ToString(), propertyToParse, parent);
    }
    dbg(propertyToParse + ": " + valToReturn);
    return valToReturn;
}
```

Example code to call both functions above is:

```
this.authToken = await this.sM.Getter(this.MethodBuilder("auth.gettoken"), "token");
string response = await this.sM.Poster(this.MethodBuilder("auth.getMobileSession", true, vP, true), vP);
```

So I've now used `ConfigureAwait(false);` for my `Getter` function - and the HTTP call is now being made correctly. *However* it's still not progressing from my first `authToken` line above to the `response` line

**EDIT: Turns out I had a blocker in my code after all - one of my top level functions was relying on `this.VARIABLE = sM.Getter().Result()`. Removing that ended up fixing my issue. Thanks all for the help!**

Comment: What do you mean "dying". What's the response message and response status code you get? What is the exception?

Comment: Have you tried fiddler?

Comment: How are you calling these methods? Show that code. It looks like you have a deadlock.

Comment: Jinish: As in, it just locks up - looking at my profiler shows me that the correct URI is passed and is being processed. There are no exceptions or response messages/codes - the code simply....hangs. My profiler is also not showing any further calls being made after that line


Ben: To see if it's actually calling the URI? Haven't yet


DavidG: editing my post

Comment: Still getting used to SO, apologies for the formatting above - didn't realise it doesn't split lines in comments

Comment: You're trying to get it right, that's 90% of the way there, so thanks for that! Thanks for the update, but I guess it's not enough. Do you `await` everything in the chain all the way to the top level?

Comment: Yep, everything is `await`ed - as I mentioned, this exact code worked for _months_ - it's only since I've formatted that it's stopped working. The GET/POST methods are fundamental to my program, so if they hadn't worked, the rest of the project wouldn't have worked at all

Comment: All of my calling functions are `public async Task<responseType> functionName {}`, and called via `await`

Comment: Have you tried using `ConfigureAwait`? e.g. `await hClient.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Yep, then that ends up breaking me being able to get the responses from the various functions. It's late where I'm at, so will try using `ConfigureAwait` again when I'm back on my PC in the morning

Comment: At the top of the call chain, do you do anything like `.Wait()` for example? There's a reason you're getting a deadlock.

Comment: Just stepped through all my calling functions - they're all `async`, and they're all `await`ing the commands - none are `.Wait()`ed

Comment: Added details in the edit above - `ConfigureAwait(false)` has been added, but it's now not returning control to my calling function to progress. All threads are exiting with code `0x0`

Comment: Turns out the issue was in a calling function after all. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a blocker in my code after all - one of my top level functions was relying on `this.VARIABLE = sM.Getter().Result();`. Removing that ended up fixing my issue. Thanks all for the help!